# Finding the probability density function of $U=Y_1+Y_2$

Tags: statistics

Let $(Y_1,Y_2)$ denote a random sample of $n=2$ from the uniform distribution function on (0,1).

(1) Find the probability density function $U=Y_1+Y_2$

(2) Find $E(U)$

I am unsure of how to bound the integrals for this.

- I think that I need to consider four different situations:

a) $U<0$

b) $0 \le U \le 1$

c) $ 1\le U \le 2$

d) $ U>2$

I have draw the pictures for each of these.  I know  that:

a)=0 since:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}0dy_2dy_1=0$$

but I am not sure how to find b,c,d. I think finding E(U) will be easy once I have (1) completed. I assume I will need to find $E(u)=E(Y_1+Y_2)$

My guess at b:

$$\int_0^u \int_0^{U-y_2} 1dy_1dy_2 = \frac{1}{2}u^2 $$

are these bounds correct?

I also know that d)=1 since:

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 1dy_2dy_1=1$$

I need help setting up the bounds for c. Also, I am not positive how I would find E(u) here.

**EDIT**

Based on the comments, I think this is E(u)

$$E(U)=E(Y_1+Y_2)=E(Y_1)+E(Y_2)$$ $$\int_0^1 y_1dy1 +\int_0^1 y_2 dy_2 = 1$$

is that correct? Or would I need to change the upper bound of those integrals so that I use the line $u=y_1+y_2$?

Comment: You do not need to solve 1) in order to answer 2). _Linearity of expectation_ tells us that $E[U]=E[Y_1+Y_2] = E[Y_1]+E[Y_2]$.

Comment: For expectation we really don't need (1), since by the linearity of expectation $E(Y_1+Y_2)=E(Y_1)+E(Y_2)$. For the density your case splitting is good. Are you going to use a convolution to find the density directly, or will you go through the cumulative distribution function?

Comment: Andre - I will use the method of distribution of functions. We are learning each of the methods for solving such problems and I have been explicitly instructed to use this method alone.

Comment: @AndréNicolas -

Comment: Wii try to comment later,to help you on your way. This question has been abswered on MSE several times, so I will not write a formal answer. Your expectation calculation is correct, or we could use symmetry.

Comment: Let $F_U(u)$ be the cdf of $U$. As you saw, $F_U(u)=0$ if $u\lt 0$, so there $f_U(u)-0$. If $u\gt 2$, it is clear that $F_U(u)=\Pr(U\le u)=1$ so $f_U(u)=0$. If $0\lt u\lt 1$, then $F_U(u)=\int_{y_1=0}^u \int_{y_2=0}^{u-y_1}\,dy_2\,dy_1$. (We are integrating over the part of the unit square that is "below" the line $y_1+y_2=u$.) More simply, we want the area of a certain isosceles right triangle with legs $u$. We get $\frac{u^2}{2}$ so density $u$. (More coming)

Comment: Finally, for $1\lt u\lt 2$, if we use an integral we have to break it up, first part $\int_0^{u-1}\int_0^1\,dy_2\,dy_1$, second part $\int_{u-1}^1\int_0^{u-y_1}\,dy_2\,dy_1$. But far clearer by geometry $F_U(u)$ is $1$ minus the area pf  an isosceles right triangle with leg $1-u$, so we get $1-(1-u)^2$, density $2-u$. Sorry about the cramped exposition, comments have typesetting limitations.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - Thank you for this!

Comment: You are welcome. The real answer should include a picture, which makes everything clear. We are integrating $1$ over the part of the unit square that is below the line $x+y=u$ (oops, $y_1+y_2=u$). Or more simply we are finding an areas. The geometry is a little different in the case $0\lt u\lt 1$ than in the case $1\lt u\lt 2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - No worries - I drew the pictures myself. I understood everything myself aside from part c. For the integration, I had trouble understanding why the lower bound for the $dy_2$ integral was $u-1$ and note that I used $1 - \int_{u-1}^1 \int_{u-y_2}^1 1dy_1dy_2$

Comment: Yes, in the interval $1\lt u\lt 2$ it is natural to go after the probability of the complement. The line $y_1+y_2=u$ meets the upper line $y_2=1$ at $y_1=u-1$, so that;s where $y_1$ starts. Better, for this problem, is to let $Z_1=1-Y_1$, $Z_2=1-Y_2$. Then $Z_1, Z_2$ are uniform and $1\lt Y_1+Y_2\lt 2$ iff $0\lt Z_1+Z_2\lt 1$. So the density function is symmetric about $u=1$.